# How do I parse a Microsoft JSON date in Python?

Tags: python, json

I have to read a JSON file and It has the date fields formated like this below

`"MyDate": "/Date(1603284014088)/"`,

I found some examples to parse it in other languages (JavaScript, Kotlin) but nothing in Python.

I could find on this SCOTT HANSELMAN's post [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/on-the-nightmare-that-is-json-dates-plus-jsonnet-and-aspnet-web-api) that they are milliseconds since the beginning of the Unix Epoch sometimes with a TimeZone. So I could write a simple function to decode it.

```
import re
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def decode_date (encoded_date):
    mask = "\/Date\(([0-9]*)\)"
    offset = datetime(1970, 1, 1)
    my_matchs = re.match(mask, encoded_date).groups()
    if len(my_matchs) == 1:
        return datetime(1970, 1, 1) + timedelta(milliseconds=int(my_matchs[0]))
    else:
        return None
    

encoded = "/Date(1603284014088)/"
print (decode_date(encoded))
```

This function can't parse dates with timezone because I'm lazy :), My question is - is there some lib that can parse it out of the box in Python?

Comment: You don't - you tell whoever created that service that eve ASP.NET Web API uses ISO8601 for dates. Nobody uses that Unix timestamp for almost 10 years

Comment: You can use `datetime.fromtimestamp` to convert the Unix timestamp value directly, there's no need to do it yourself

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I could live with milliseconds-since-the-epoch being returned. What *really* isn't necessary is the `/Date(...)` wrapper around it.

Comment: I edited my code to deal with not match strings.. I absolutellly agree with Panagiotis Kanavos but it was a ended project already validated I can ask that guy to change it now.

Comment: Hello, did you have a moment to check my reply? If it was useful for you please consider upvoting it and / or choosing it as final answer. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Given the fact that you are already able to extract the date using RegEx please try the following code for conversion:

```
import datetime

s = '1603284014088'
fmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

# Local time
t = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(s)/1000.)
print (t.strftime(fmt))

# UTC time
t_utc = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(float(s)/1000.)
print (t_utc.strftime(fmt))
```

Comment: The call to `float` isn't necessary. Dividing by a float will produce a float result. In Python 3, `/` will *always* produce a float, even if both arguments are `int`s, so `s/1000` is sufficient.

Comment: @chepner `s` is a string so you need the call to `float`.

Comment: Oh, sorry, got ahead of myself. I assumed `s` was already an `int`.

Comment: But that said, `int(s)/1000` would be sufficient and "stricter", as it is expected that `s` is the string representation of an `int`.